# How to change Flutter Firebase Firestore Document name?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firebase Firestore. I want to rename a `document` in this collection. How can I do that? The data in it should not be affected.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [How to rename documents in firebase firestore](https://medium.com/@xathis/how-to-rename-documents-in-firebase-firestore-bc0463144ed1)

or I think the best way to do this is to get the data from 'name@xxx.com' and upload it to a new document called 'name' and then delete the old one.